# How to store an image?

Tags: php, symfony

I don't understand [Gaufrette](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle) and symfony2.

[This](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette#try-it) seems to me like it's only working for textfiles/textcontent.
I can create a file but can't copy from a local source (i.e. a path).

What i would like to do is something like this:

```
$adapter = new LocalAdapter($realpath);
$filesystem = new Filesystem($adapter);
$filesystem->fromUploadedFile($tempPathOfUploadedFile,$idForGaufrette);
```

How do I store an image and how do I handle it's output when requested by the user?

**Update:**

- How can I access the temp filename of an uploaded file in symfony"?
- How can I access the existing, private attribute $path that exists in the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` Object in Symfony2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `copy(x, y)` is not implemented but if you want storing a file you can move it using the method 
`rename($key, $new)`
defined in the [Filesystem Class](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette/blob/master/src/Gaufrette/Filesystem.php#L46).

For handle the output when requested by the user, all you need is a link to the image path (probaly in the database). So you don't need the filesystem (you can check if the file exists with the `has($key)` method).

In all cases use the adapter [Local](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette/blob/master/src/Gaufrette/Adapter/Local.php) to work in local.

If you need a stream wrapper like "ftp://mydomain/myPicture" i recently send a [PR](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpGaufretteBundle#stream-wrapper) to configures the stream wrapper in the config.yml, and register filiesystems that you want and their domain.

Comment: i think you got me wrong. What i search for is a solution to not have to physically store the file somewhere after it is received from the request, and then store it to the gaufrette adapter.

Comment: But @AndreschSerj when you receive a file from a form it's "PHP" which stores the file in "tmp/bigKey" you can write this file with gaufrette in another filesystems like amazon, ftp etc...
But if you don't want stock the file or move the file, what are the operations you want with GAUFRETTE in this file ?

Comment: Well it seems my question here is more focused on symfony then. I want access to the temporarily stored file to then put that to Gaufrette without any detours. How can i get the "tmp/bigKey" path?

Comment: I edited my question and added the question to asko for "How to get the tmp filename"

Comment: This is in my opinion wrong. Why would you store the image path in the database?! Gaufrette is made that you don't need to care about where the file is stored. You just need the name and the gaufrette service. Storing the path would be nonsense, e. g when you upgrade from local adapter to Amazon s3, all stored paths would be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

To get the tmp filename:

```
$file->getPathName(); // /tmp/filename
```

where $file is a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` Object.